# Chaser Menu in Javascript Doesn't Show When Scrolled, Always Hidden

Tags: javascript, joomla, web

I'm trying to make a chaser menu (shows up when the window scrolls down).

I got this code and try to copy-paste it to my site.

```
$(function ($) {
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////// START - CODE FOR LOADING THE TOP MENU CHASING BAR
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var doc = $(document), win = $(window), chaser, forch,
        forchBottom, visible;
    function shown() {
        visible = true;
    }
    function hidden() {
        visible = false;
    }
    chaser = $('.rt-menubar.fusionmenu').clone().hide().appendTo(document.body).wrap("<div class='chaser'></div>");
    forch = $('.forchaser').first();
    forchBottom = forch.height() + forch.offset().top;
    hidden();
    win.bind('scroll', function () {
        var top = doc.scrollTop();
        if (!visible && top > forchBottom) {
            chaser.slideDown(300, shown);
        } else if (visible && top < forchBottom) {
            chaser.slideUp(200, hidden);
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the result of what I got:

```
<div class="rt-menubar fusionmenu" style="display: none;">
//code of list menu
</div>
```

Problem is, no matter how I scroll the windows scrollbar, it's always set 'display: none' instead of 'display: block'. So it's always hidden.

If I eliminate the hide() function in the chaser variable code a little bit to:

```
chaser = $('.rt-menubar.fusionmenu').clone().appendTo(document.body).wrap("<div class='chaser'></div>");
```

The chaser menu appears and works fine. However, it's not what I want. I want the chaser menu to hide at the top of page, and showed when I scroll down the window.

How to fix this?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

I forget to put:

```
<div class="forchaser"></div>
```

somewhere in the main body area. It's to give a mark as a starting point where you chaser menu will be showed.